# Why Does this Sandbox in C#, Velcro, and SFML Have Such Inconsistent Collisions

Tags: c#, physics

I wired up a basic sandbox in C# using Velcro for physics and SFML for display; four walls and a ball with velocity and bounce.  The problem is that various combinations of the initial velocity result in equally various instances of the ball passing through the walls.  Sometimes the ball will pass through the first wall it hits.  Other times, the second.  The only thing that seems consistent is that, when I make the velocity perfectly vertical or perfectly horizontal, the ball seems to bounce indefinitely.

```
using SFML.System;
using SFML.Window;
using SFML.Graphics;
using VelcroPhysics.Factories;
using VelcroPhysics.Dynamics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace TVTennis
{
    class Program
    {
        public const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1600;
        public const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1200;
        public const byte SCREEN_BPP = 16;

        public const int WORLD_WIDTH = 160;
        public const int WORLD_HEIGHT = 120;

        public const byte COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_R = 64;
        public const byte COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_G = 255;
        public const byte COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_B = 64;

        public const int BALL_RADIUS = 1;
        public const int BALL_START_POSITION_X = 20;
        public const int BALL_START_POSITION_Y = WORLD_HEIGHT / 2;
        public const float BALL_START_VELOCITY_X = 40.0F;
        public const float BALL_START_VELOCITY_Y = -80.0F;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var world = new World(new Vector2(0.0F));

            var ball = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, BALL_RADIUS, 1.0F, new Vector2(BALL_START_POSITION_X, BALL_START_POSITION_Y), BodyType.Dynamic);
            ball.LinearVelocity = new Vector2(BALL_START_VELOCITY_X, BALL_START_VELOCITY_Y);
            ball.Restitution = 1.0F;

            var wallLeft = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.0F, WORLD_HEIGHT, 1.0F, new Vector2(0.0F, 0.0F), 0.0F, BodyType.Static);
            var wallRight = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.0F, WORLD_HEIGHT, 1.0F, new Vector2(WORLD_WIDTH - 1.0F, 0.0F), 0.0F, BodyType.Static);
            var wallTop = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, WORLD_WIDTH, 1.0F, 1.0F, new Vector2(1.0F, 0.0F), 0.0F, BodyType.Static);
            var wallBottom = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, WORLD_WIDTH, 1.0F, 1.0F, new Vector2(1.0F, WORLD_HEIGHT - 1.0F), 0.0F, BodyType.Static);

            float displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX = SCREEN_WIDTH / WORLD_WIDTH;
            float displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY = SCREEN_HEIGHT / WORLD_HEIGHT;

            Color terminalGreen = new Color(COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_R, COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_G, COLOR_TERMINALGREEN_B);
            Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);

            var ballSprite = new RectangleShape(new Vector2f(BALL_RADIUS * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, BALL_RADIUS * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX));
            var verticalWallSprite = new RectangleShape(new Vector2f(1.0F * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, WORLD_HEIGHT * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY));
            var horizontalWallSprite = new RectangleShape(new Vector2f((WORLD_WIDTH - 2.0F) * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, 1.0F * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY));

            ballSprite.FillColor = terminalGreen;
            verticalWallSprite.FillColor = terminalGreen;
            horizontalWallSprite.FillColor = terminalGreen;

            var screen = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP), "TV Tennis");
            var clock = new Clock();

            while (!Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Escape))
            {
                float deltaTime = clock.ElapsedTime.AsSeconds();
                clock.Restart();

                world.Step(deltaTime);

                System.Console.WriteLine("BALL: " + ball.Position.X + "," + ball.Position.Y);

                screen.Clear(black);

                ballSprite.Position = new Vector2f(ball.Position.X * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, ball.Position.Y * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY);
                ballSprite.Draw(screen, RenderStates.Default);

                verticalWallSprite.Position = new Vector2f(wallLeft.Position.X * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, wallLeft.Position.Y * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY);
                verticalWallSprite.Draw(screen, RenderStates.Default);

                verticalWallSprite.Position = new Vector2f(wallRight.Position.X * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, wallRight.Position.Y * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY);
                verticalWallSprite.Draw(screen, RenderStates.Default);

                horizontalWallSprite.Position = new Vector2f(wallTop.Position.X * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, wallTop.Position.Y * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY);
                horizontalWallSprite.Draw(screen, RenderStates.Default);

                horizontalWallSprite.Position = new Vector2f(wallBottom.Position.X * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitX, wallBottom.Position.Y * displayPixelsPerWorldUnitY);
                horizontalWallSprite.Draw(screen, RenderStates.Default);

                screen.DispatchEvents();
                screen.Display();

            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any real experience with Velcro, but this sounds a lot like you're most likely using values (position/speed) at a scale not suitable for Velcro. All physics engines have a recommended range for your values you should try to stay inside for things such as accuracy.

Comment: Velcro <- Farseer <- Box2D

Comment: @Mario  Per your response, I tried scaling my world size back to 8.0 by 6.0 and all other sizes and dimensions accordingly.  This did not help.

Comment: Looks like you need to enable continuous collision detection

Comment: (not sure how you should do that though, I guess it's hidden somewhere in the docs)

Comment: The answer turns out to be that the screen representation had a major flaw; namely that the positions returned by Velcro were fixture midpoints and not top left bounding box corners as I had assumed.  This caused the physics objects that represented the walls to only cover about half of the edge.